# MVC Unobtrusive validation data-val-* markup attributes not being generated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, unobtrusive-validation

**Edit:** It seems as though no attributes work whatsoever, validation or not. For example, [DataType(DataType.Date)] doesn't change the markup in anyway either, while it should add 'type=date' to the element, the [Authorize] attribute lets even unauthorized users through etc. Anywone have any ideas about what could be the problem?

**Edit 2:** Added the following while trying to figure out what's wrong:

```
ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(m => m.Name, Html.ViewData);
var val = metadata.GetValidators(new ControllerContext());
var attributes = metadata.ContainerType.GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name == "Name").FirstOrDefault().CustomAttributes;
```

The 'val' variable doesn't return any validators, while in a new project the same line works correctly and returns an IEnumerable of all the attributes the model property has. The 'attributes' variable, though, does find all the attributes the property has. So where do I go from here and find out what's wrong?

**Edit 3:** So I compared what the property 'ModelValidatorProviders.Providers' returns in Global.asax's 'Application_Start()' method between my project and a new project and it turns out that for some reason for my project it doesn't have a 'DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider'. So I did this at 'Application_Start()':

```
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider());
```

*And now the validation works* (except the [Authorize] attribute and others not related to models, it looks like they still dont work)! Not much of a fix, though, is it. Why isn't the provider in the ModelValidatorProviders property in the first place? Could it have anything to do with the fact that I have Autofac installed and maybe that messes with it somehow?

**Edit 4:** Fixed it, see answer.

**Original post:**

I'm pulling my hair out at this point, because I've read multiple articles about this and none of them help. The weird part is that the validation worked before and then it suddenly stopped working (I didn't change anything). I even restarted my PC, but that didn't really help.

- Yes, both ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled are set to true in web.config
- The required validation JavaScript files work fine too - they are imported correctly and load fine, but the problem doesn't even reach those, because the serverside isn't even generating the required HTML markup.

My ViewModel looks like this (the validation doesn't work anywhere on the site, so I could give you literally any viewmodel):

```
public class ChangePasswordViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Current password")]
    public string OldPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "New password")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
    [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the view (pretty much the default MVC view as well, so there's nothing wrong with it):

```
@model AwenterWeb.Models.ChangePasswordViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Change Password";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "Manage", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Change Password Form</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.OldPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.OldPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.NewPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Change password" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

I put a breakpoint on Html.TextBoxFor and made sure that indeed the HTML that it returns does not have the necessary validation attributes. 
What else could be broken? It is definitely not an issue with the Validation JS files, but rather Html.TextBoxFor and other helper classes for some reason can't tell that the fields have attributes on them!

Comment: Are the script files definitely included in the layout and are they being loaded (i.e. if you look at network traffic in the browser, do they get sent)? Can you list the javascript files you're using?

Comment: I emphasized this in the post - it is definitely not a problem with JavaScript, because the wrong markup is generated way before the JS is even loaded  (the wrong markup is generated at serverside when the Html.EditorFor function runs and returns the input element without the data-val-* attributes)! If you must know then yes the JS files load fine, I can see them in the page source and in the network tab. I'm not using any other JS files other than the ones that come with the project.

Comment: @Fabis The model you have posted is completely different to the one in your view. Please post the model in the view.

Comment: I edited the post, but it doesn't really matter anyway, because as I've said no validation works anywhere on the whole site.

Comment: Well, the Html.TextBoxFor() returns the element without the attributes even though (as you can see) I have the correct annotations set up, so the problem is somewhere within the Html.TextBoxFor() function. Could it be a bug?

Comment: What version of MVC are you using? Is this MVC 5?

Comment: Yes, the latest stable build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a whole day of trying to figure out what could possibly be wrong I decided to completely uninstall any traces of Autofac and Ninject I had (don't know why I had Ninject, don't remember ever installing it) and surprise, surprise things started working again. I then reinstalled the latest versions of the Autofac packages I had and attributes still worked, so maybe it had something to do with those rogue Ninject packages.

I still don't know why exactly Autofac or Ninject would mess with how attributes and validation work, without me explicitly telling them to do so, but at this point I don't even care.

Hopefully this helps someone!